# Alter the precision of an existing decimal column in SQL Server 2014 results in error

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a couple decimal columns in a couple tables that I need to expand from `decimal(9, 4)` to `decimal(9, 5)`. Unfortunately I get the following error every way I try. So far I have tried changing it using design in SQL Server Management Studio and running the query:

```
alter table xxx 
alter column xxx decimal (9,5) not null
```

The error is the same:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

These are large, important tables that are used in dozens of stored procedures and applications so I want to avoid adding a new column and copying the data over. Each table has between 250K and 500K rows.

Any ideas would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: `decimal(9,4)` means: 9 digits total, 4 of which after the decimal point, thus 5 before the decimal point. Changing that to `decimal(9,5)` increases the number of digits *after* the decimal point from 4 to 5, but it **decreases** the number of digits *before* the decimal point from 5 downto 4 - that won't fly if you have any numbers over 9999.99 ...... you need to change to `decimal(10,5)` instead !! Consulting [the official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) would have told you that, too ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you have reduced the number of significant digits when you changed the datatype. If you have any rows with a value of 100,000 or greater it won't fit inside the new size. If you want to increase the number of decimal places (scale) you will also need to increase the precision by 1.

```
alter table xxx alter COLUMN xxx decimal (10,5) not null
```

Please note, this will increase the storage requirements of each row by 4 bytes. The storage requirement will increase from 5 bytes to 9 bytes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx